# PHP random glob sort

Tags: php, list, glob

I have this simple line:

```
       $images = glob($directory . "*.html");
```

It returns a list of files like this: 

**e.g 1**

```
17001400300120110004600.html
17001400300120110004700.html
17001400300120110004800.html
17001400300120110004900.html
17001400300120110005000.html
```

The problem is that I don't need an ordered list. I need a random list, like this:

**e.g 2**

```
17001400300120110004700.html
17001400300120110005000.html
17001400300120110004900.html
17001400300120110004600.html
17001400300120110005800.html
```

I've tried with `NOSORT ( $images = glob($directory . "*.html", GLOB_NOSORT); )` flag but returns an ordered list like in the first example.

How can I get a random list?

Comment: Just do something like `shuffle($images);`

Comment: The reason they're sorted even when you use `NOSORT` is because it uses the order they exist in the directory, which is often the order the files were created, and they were probably created in numerical order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on array returned from glob.

Using nosort won't make your array random, it will just read them in order they appear in the directory instead of sorting them by name, as documentation states:

> GLOB_NOSORT - Return files as they appear in the directory (no
>   sorting)

Have in mind that `shuffle` takes array as referrence so you will need to do just this:

```
$images = glob($directory . "*.html");
shuffle($images);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$images = shuffle(glob($directory . "*.html"));
```

Comment: shuffle returns a boolean as can be read in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). Therefore this won't work